# how find the identical rows in a DataFrame -- python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame A as follows, and I want to find the rows with the same values in their first 3 columns.

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import numpy as np
import datetime
A= """
   c0   c1   c2   c3   c4
0  1    a    d    3    4
1  1    a    c    0    0
2  1    a    d    3    1
3  1    b    c    0    0
4  2    b    d    8    5
5  2    b    d    3    3
    """

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(A), delimiter='\s+')
df2= pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['c0', 'c1', 'c2'])
for i in range(0,4):
    row1 = df2.irow(i)
    row2 = df2.irow(i+1)
    val=all(unique_columns = row1 != row2)   
    print(i)
```

I want it to print `2, 5`.

Well, this does not work, even if it would it couldn't get the rows that are following eachother.

Alternatively, I tried `np.unique(df2)`, to see if the number of columns are different from `df2`, which didn't work either.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: ...but only the row 2 has the same values in c0-c2 as the row 0, row 6 does not.

Comment: @CTZhu, yes, but row 5 has the same value as row 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC then use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html#pandas.DataFrame.duplicated):

```
In [132]:
df2.index[df2.duplicated()]

Out[132]:
Int64Index([2, 6], dtype='int64')
```

So this works because it detects when any row has duplicate values, as `df2` is a subset of the cols of interest then all columns are tested.

**EDIT**

`df2` seems superfluous here you can just do:

```
In [133]:
df.index[df.duplicated(subset=['c0', 'c1', 'c2'])]

Out[133]:
Int64Index([2, 6], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: Possibly include `subset` since only first 3 columns are needed.

Comment: You're right,  the OP might need to consider removing df2 to prevent unnecessary steps and possibly doubling the data

Answer (score 1):

```
In [211]: a.groupby(['c0','c1','c2']).indices
Out[211]:
{(1, 'a', 'c'): array([1]),
 (1, 'a', 'd'): array([0, 2]),
 (1, 'b', 'c'): array([3]),
 (2, 'b', 'd'): array([4, 5])}
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: This is great for when you actually care about the groups and want to categorize your data. Thanks.